# Effective rendering of occluded field of view plane in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, game-engine

I have simulator similar to RTS game where I have an agent position with its own field of view.I want to visualize this.Something similar to games like "Commandos" .Now , it is quite easy to create such a filed like a triangulated cone shaped 2d plane.But I would also want it to get occluded by obstacles.What is the the best strategy for doing it?My current thought is to use Stencil test for all the geometry before rendering the cone but it still means I have somehow to mark the occluded areas before the test.Should I do some PVS maybe?How  is it done in games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same problem as shadow casting from a point light. Depending on your exact requirements, any point-light shadowing technique, such as stencil shadowing or some form of shadow mapping will work.

Comment: But how do I restrict the shadow for view cone not to pass obstacles. That's what I can't figure out ...

Comment: You have the obstacles generate the shadows. I.e. you mask out the regions that are occluded from your view point, either via silhouette extraction (like stencil shadowing) or via some sort of depth buffering (like shadow mapping)